# Display the IP addresses of all currently configured interfaces

Tags: bash, scripting, ip, interface

Display the IP addresses of all currently configured interfaces. The output should
done in the following format:i

The interface eth0 currently has the IP 192.168.178.22
The interface eth1 currently has the IP 192.168.178.23
...etc.

Comment: Sounds like a (homework) exercise meant to be done by looping over the output of (something like) `ip a s`.

Comment: OP didn't even say Linux was used...

Comment: It is not clear what Unix you are using.

Answer (score 1):

if we are talking about Linux, this one-liner in `bash` maybe helps you:

```
ip -br -4 address | awk '{ print $1 " interface has the ip address " $3}'
```

Answer (score -2):

Make yourself familiar with the concept of *pipes*.

Then use the commands `ip`, and some bash builtins like `read` and `while` to filter and enhance the output.

See `man bash`.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).